# Jagged font issue on Full HDTV Display on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, high-dpi, hdtv, cleartype, font-smoothing

Those who jump in as soon as seen the title, I know this is an ongoing problem for years and I just wanted to check if there has been any development about this issue. It seems Microsoft won't fix it anytime soon. Still, I would like to tell you guys what I have tried so far:

1. Right-click the application and check the DPI thing on the compatibility tab
2. On Regedit, add the "Win8DPIScaling" key and set it. Also, LogPixels key set to 78
3. Cleartype, of course
4. Changed TV's own settings (like aspect ratio, color management, gamma, etc)
5. Display settings on Windows (tried every option)
6. Advanced system options -> performance -> smooth edges

Did I miss anything? If I did, please let me know. And also, as I said in the beginning, I would like to know if there has been any development about this issue.

Comment: You do realise "Full HD" is very low resolution compared to a dedicated computer monitor? The bigger the TV, the worse this is going to look. It's not 'fixable' because you don't have enough pixels to 'fix' it.

Comment: @Tetsujin Then tell me why it was fixable on Windows 8? People say that btw, not me. Am I missing something here?